# MSM on local development sites

Tags: multi-site-manager, php-errors, localhost

I am trying to create a multi site locally on my machine with MAMP PRO. So far I have installed the local ee fine but for some reason when I try to click Site in the home admin page I get a server error.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: "Click Site". Where are you clicking this?

Comment: In the create area when in home admin page. I tried clicking in the top right too, where my site name was I tried to click 'Edit sites'. This is where the error then popped up again.

Comment: And what was the error? If you can provide as much information as possible it makes helping a lot easier.

Comment: As its local all I get is this error: The website encountered an error while retrieving http://arcadialookbook:8888/admin.php?S=1798a6399e9b306166fd5e58fd93bc6394da7e00&D=cp&C=sites&M=manage_sites. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly. Is there anything I can do to output any php errors in a debug.php file?

Comment: The first thing I would do is check my MAMP log files and then look in my htaccess file for any redirects that might be causing it.

Comment: There is no .htaccess file on my root at the moment which is strange considering I configured the urls properly in the ee system. I also checked the error logs and nothing unusual was coming up in the mysql logs or php logs. I think it could be down to the .htaccess but I am unsure as to what would go in there to aid in stopping the errors for MSM